# Specific set of shapes

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need 2d shapes with less than seven sides, 180 degree rotational symmetry, and two-fold linear symmetry for a unity project. I already have:

  square, 
  circle, 
  hexagon

*I know this is probably not the correct site for this question, but I don't know where else to put it.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's off-topic and more appropriate for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Once you figure out what shapes you need, you can google "unity3d procedural mesh geometry" to learn how to generate meshes with maths.